# Работа NavigationDrawer Activity и Fragments

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! В Андроиде новичок. Я хотел бы написать приложение для различных расписаний, в первую очередь для школьников и студентов. Приложение, по моей задумке состоит из NavigationDrawer с такими вкладками: Расписание, Оценки, Экзамены (и зачеты) и Задания. Во вкладке с расписанием должен быть TabLayout с днями недели. Суть вопроса заключается в следующем, по своей реализации NavigationDrawer должен работать с фрагментами (это как я понял задумка гугла), чтобы он (NavigationDrawer) был доступен по всему приложению, с Активностями NavigationDrawer пропадает. Дак вот, Как можно реализовать структуру, описанную выше? Я пробовал создавать фрагмент с табами, при нажатии на день недели появляется фрагмент с днем недели, но данный подход кажется мне некорректным, т.к. при запуске приложения фрагменты работают нормально, но если в NavigationDrawer перейти, например, в Оценки и затем вернуться в Расписание, то после этого фрагменты ничего не отображают и табы не переключаются корректно, т.е. на какое расстояние провел пальцем, на столько таба и сдвинулась, при этом информации на ней ноль. Если вручную нажать на последнюю или предпоследнюю табу, то там появляется информация и затем табы нормально начинают работать.
Что делать в данной ситуации, не знаю. Гугление особо ничего не дало. Практически везде TabLayout реализуют внутри Активности, а не во фрагменте. Да и в таком случае, табы будут во всех фрагментах. Или все же есть какой то способ совместить табы, активность и NavigationDrawer?
и можно как нибудь при вызове фрагмента, убрать табы, если они организованны на уровне активности ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно задать контейнер для главной активности

```
   <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
        </RelativeLayout>
```

И вызывать фрагменты по необходимости с помощью

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Fragment()).addToBackStack("tag").commit();
```

также в oncreate указать старт фрагмент

Comment: у меня в MainActivity идет инициализация NavigationDrawer и его пунктов меню, то есть при запуске, у меня запускается фрагмент с табами, которые в свою очередь содержит фрагменты с днями недели.
то есть в onCreate (MainActivity) прописал
`ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.add(R.id.container, daysFragment);
 ft.commit();`
тем самым вызываю тот самый фрагмент с табами

Comment: @vaseel1ch , да

Comment: то есть то, что я описал в вопросе, свою реализацию, она считается правильной ? что я во фрагменте создал TabLayout с ViewPager'ом, и в этом TabLayout содержатся другие фрагменты

Comment: @vaseel1ch ,  можно внутри фрагмента вызывать фрагменты сколько угодно, также можно накладывать один фрагмент на другой с помощью .add() [почитать можно тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php)